# How to read the content of an .eds file and store it in a table?

Tags: python, dataframe, dataset

We are trying to read some data in Python from this URL: https://atmos.nmsu.edu/PDS/data/mors_1102/eds/1998_358/8358d47a.eds

we are trying read the content of the file starting from row 2 and store it in a table of 6 columns.
Then use the first row to extract the entries 14,18, and 19 and add three columns to the table each containing these entries.

Anyone can help me in this?

I have downloaded the file from the website as an .eds file and tried to open and read it using the following code:

```
import csv

file_path = r'C:\Users\202958\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\MGS\1998_358\8358d47a.eds'
data = []

with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)

for i in range(min(5, len(data))):
    print(data[i])
```

but still I don't get the content of the files tore in "data".

Comment: No need to download the data. Just use: `import pandas as pd` then `data=pd.read_csv("https://atmos.nmsu.edu/PDS/data/mors_1102/eds/1998_358/8358d47a.eds")`

Comment: You only print (at most) 5 lines from the EDS file